# No such file or directory when installing liblinear for use on Ubuntu in MATLAB

Tags: software-installation, matlab

MATLAB version is 2010a Student Version (32 bit), Ubuntu version is 13.04, 64 bit.

I first use make in the directory liblinear-1.94. This step works.

Then I `cd` into the MATLAB directory and attempt to use make. The error is as follows:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open linker script file /usr/local/matlabR2010a/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

mex: link of ' "train.mexa64"' failed.

make: *** [train.mexa64] Error 1
```

I basically know why the error exists but don't know how to fix it. There is no folder called glnxa64. Instead, there is a folder called glnx86. This is because my version of MATLAB is 32 bit, but Ubuntu is 64 bit. It seems that the make file is trying to access a folder that would exist if MATLAB was the 64 bit version.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: does matlab otherwise work?  I've herd the install on x64 usually doesn't go well and thus am currently trying octave (but there's command compatibility problems there as well)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ln -s /usr/local/matlabR2010a/extern/lib/glnx86 /usr/local/matlabR2010a/extern/lib/glnxa64
```